# html email: table background image not displaying

Tags: html, css, email

I tried to use a background image for a table as follows:

```
<table style='background-image:url(cid:email_title_background)'>
```

It displays fine in my browser. However, when I check the real email in Outlook and Gmail, the image cannot be seen.

I have checked https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/, which may explain why Outlook failed, but what about Gmail?

Also tried the approach in https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2010/06/adding-background-images-to-your-email-in-two-simple-steps/, same result...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: background-image with an actual URL and background-image with a linked resource are likely two different issues. Gmail probably doesn't support that. I feel your pain with creating HTML email messages.

Comment: I agree with @Rick as well. I have suffered a lot of email formatting, not only between Gmail and Outlook but then even across different versions of Outlook. Solutions I have often turning to in the past are finding a service (such as MailChimp) that will send out emails for me and often have more sophisticated formatting than I can output, creating just one giant image for the email or perhaps making a website that looks like an email and giving out links to it somehow. good luck! it can be a horrible pain

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `background` attribute of table element instead of using CSS attributes. It is the best way to avoid problems in different e-mail clients.

Source: http://blog.mailchimp.com/background-images-and-css-in-html-email/

Example **(Tested with Litmus - Gmail and Outlook)**:

```
<table background="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg" width="550" height="368">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Content
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```